# How to change the count of a pthread_barrier?

Tags: c, pthreads

The problem is that we have to implement a kind of "running-contest" using pthreads. After one track we have to wait until all runners/threads are done until this point, so we use a barrier for that.

But now we also have to implement the probability of injuries. So we wrote a function, which sometimes reduces the number of runners, and reinitialize the barrier with a smaller count. Now the problem is that the program is not always terminating. I guess the reason for this is that some of the threads have already been at the barrier, and after reinitializing them the required amount is not arriving.

The code for the simulation of the injury looks like this:

```
void simulateInjury(int number) {
    int totalRunners = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if (rand() % 10 < 1) {
        printf("Runner of Team %i injured!\n", number);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&evaluate_teamsize);
        standings.teamSize[number]--;
        for (i = 0; i < teams; i++) {
            totalRunners += standings.teamSize[i];
        }
        pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier_track1);
        pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier_track4[number]);
        pthread_barrier_init(&barrier_track1, NULL, totalRunners);
        pthread_barrier_init(&barrier_track4[number], NULL, standings.teamSize[number]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&evaluate_teamsize);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
}
```

Or is there maybe a way to just change the count argument of the barrier?

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors:

1. You should not re-initialize a barrier while some thread is using
   it.
2. You should not execute the re-initialization of the barrier
   simultaneously by several threads.

For the first you can create a second barrier that you use in alternation with the first.
For the second you should use the return value of the wait function to designate one particular thread that will do the re-initialization.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by in alternation? Should i just destroy the old barrier, and initialize a new one with a lower count?
2. The initialization is not done simultaneously, there is a mutex around these commands.